# Adding Multiple Content CSS to CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I actually read the documentation and followed the instructions, but ckeditor is simply ignoring any css file greater than 1.

I am using drupal 7 and I have entered the following into both the ckeditor.config.js file and Custom JavaScript configuration section in the gui.

```
config.contentsCss=['/drupal/sites/default/files/css_injector/css_injector_13.css','/drupal/sites/default/files/css_injector/css_injector_14.css'];
```

When I save the page the css displays correctly all browsers (no css mistake).  But in the ckeditor content the 2nd file is ignored.

Strangely, the code above worked for about 3 days, then I tried to add content and it completely stopped working.  Any thoughts, appreciated.

thx

Comment: You can try it adding those css file separately. That should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's exactly what I did to get things working...just annoyed that the documentation isn't correct and there's no real support.. bubble and toothpicks web development it is...

Comment: yeah i can understand. I was also facing some sort of problem due to no support.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for adding multiple css to the CKEditor content editing area -without- using config.contentCss because it appears to be simply broken. Using old school HTML within the source of the content editing area of CKEditor, simply add:

```
<link href="/path/to/my/css/files/mystyle1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/path/to/my/css/files/mystyle2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/path/to/my/css/files/mystyle3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This not a global solution, but on a per page basis it solves the problem quite effectively.

Hope someone you finds this useful.